# COUNT() OVER conditioned on the CURRENT ROW

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, window-functions

Given each row that represents a task, with start time and end time, how can I calculate the number of running tasks (i.e. that started and not ended) at the time each task starts (including itself) using a window function with `COUNT OVER`? Is a window function even the right approach?

Example, given table `tasks`:

```
task_id  start_time  end_time
   a         1          10
   b         2           5
   c         5          15
   d         8          13
   e        12          20
   f        21          30
```

Calculate `running_tasks`:

```
task_id  start_time  end_time  running_tasks
   a         1          10           1         # a
   b         2           5           2         # a,b
   c         5          15           2         # a,c (b has ended)
   d         8          13           3         # a,c,d
   e        12          20           3         # c,d,e (a has ended)
   f        21          30           1         # f (c,d,e have ended)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select      task_id,start_time,end_time,running_tasks 

from       (select      task_id,tm,op,start_time,end_time

                       ,sum(op) over 
                        (
                            order by    tm,op 
                            rows        unbounded preceding
                        ) as running_tasks 

            from       (select      task_id,start_time as tm,1 as op,start_time,end_time 
                        from        tasks 

                        union   all 

                        select      task_id,end_time as tm,-1 as op,start_time,end_time 
                        from        tasks 
                        ) t 
            )t 

where       op = 1
;
```

Comment: Dudu, thanks - smart solution, and it solves the specific simplified example.  I was hoping to get a more generalized solution where window function could be conditioned on current row - is this possible?

Comment: @NewDev, I don't get your intention so please supply an example.

Comment: Is it possible to `COUNT` over a window function with a condition to only count those rows that satisfy a condition against current row. For example, if current row's `start_time = 8`, can the window function only count rows whose `end_time > 8` and `start_time <=8`?

Comment: This query already implements an equivalent logic. The number of running task at each point **is** the number of rows that contain the current row start time. what other information do you need?

Comment: I guess what I mean is, without duplicating the rows. I'm gonna accept your answer and see if more complicated example can be better used to illustrate the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a correlated subquery, which in this case is a self-join; no analytic functions are needed. After enabling [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) (uncheck "Use Legacy SQL" under "Show Options" in the UI) you can run this example:

```
WITH tasks AS (
  SELECT
    task_id,
    start_time,
    end_time
  FROM UNNEST(ARRAY<STRUCT<task_id STRING, start_time INT64, end_time INT64>>[
    ('a', 1, 10),
    ('b', 2, 5),
    ('c', 5, 15),
    ('d', 8, 13),
    ('e', 12, 20),
    ('f', 21, 30)
  ])
)
SELECT
  *,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tasks t2
   WHERE t.start_time >= t2.start_time AND
   t.start_time < t2.end_time) AS running_tasks
FROM tasks t
ORDER BY task_id;
```

Comment: "no analytic functions are needed"? and this seems to you as an advantage?

Comment: Yes--it's generally more difficult to explain analytic functions to new SQL users than it is concepts such as joins and aggregations. In this case, the OP now has answers that give two different perspectives on the problem, which is great :)

Comment: Got it, but I would at least add a small sign - "warning! Performence danger ahead!"

Comment: Thanks Elliott... i knew about this approach, which is why the question was specific to window functions and analytics

Answer (score 2):

As Elliott has mentioned - "it's generally more difficult to explain analytic functions to new users" and even established users do not always 100% good at it (while being very very close to it)!
So, while Dudu Markovitz answer is great - unfortunatelly, it is still incorrect (at least as per how I understood question). The case when it is not correct is when you have multiple tasks started at the same start_time - so those tasks have wrong "running tasks" result

As an example - consider below example:

```
task_id  start_time  end_time
   a         1          10
   aa        1           2
   aaa       1           8
   b         2           5
   c         5          15
   d         8          13
   e        12          20
   f        21          30
```

I think, you would expect below result:

```
task_id  start_time  end_time  running_tasks
   a         1          10           3         # a,aa,aaa
   aa        1           2           3         # a,aa,aaa
   aaa       1           8           3         # a,aa,aaa
   b         2           5           3         # a,aaa,b (aa has ended)
   c         5          15           3         # a,aaa,c (b has ended)
   d         8          13           3         # a,c,d (aaa has ended)
   e        12          20           3         # c,d,e (a has ended)
   f        21          30           1         # f (c,d,e have ended)
```

If you will try it with Dudu's code  - you will get below instead

```
task_id  start_time  end_time  running_tasks
   a         1          10           1        
   aa        1           2           2        
   aaa       1           8           3        
   b         2           5           3        
   c         5          15           3        
   d         8          13           3        
   e        12          20           3        
   f        21          30           1
```

As you can see result for tasks a and aa wrong.
The reason is because of use of `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` instead of `RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` - small but very important nuance!

So below query will give you correct result

```
SELECT  task_id,start_time,end_time,running_tasks 
FROM  (
  SELECT  
    task_id, tm, op, start_time, end_time,
    SUM(op) OVER (ORDER BY  tm ,op RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS running_tasks 
  FROM  (
    SELECT  
      task_id, start_time AS tm, 1 AS op, start_time, end_time 
    FROM  tasks UNION  ALL 
    SELECT  
      task_id, end_time AS tm, -1 AS op, start_time, end_time 
    FROM  tasks 
  ) t 
)t 
WHERE  op = 1
ORDER BY start_time
```

quick summary:
ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING - sets the window frame based on rows' position
whereas
RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING - sets the window frame based on rows values

Again - as Elliott has mentioned  - this is much more complex to fully get into it than JOIN concept  - but it worth it (as it is much more efficient than joins) - see more about [Window Frame Clause](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#window-frame-clause) and ROWS vs RANGE use